# Fitting images of different sizes nicely into a collage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, photoshop

I am looking for a javascript library (or algorithm that I can implement) to fit a number of images of arbitrary sizes on a single page with little whitespace remaining. Similar to the way Google Plus displays images [[example]](https://plus.google.com/photos/109813896768294978296/albums/5632065190489236417). Or maybe even a bit more playful (google makes them identical height)

It is OK to play with the scaling of the images a bit, as long as the aspect ratios are not messed up, and things seemingly 'fit' nicely on the page.

Comment: I'd check out Masonry js or Isotope js, both seem like they'd work for you.

Comment: If you don't like either one of those. Google bin packing algorithm for the ways to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the popular library [Masonary](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

> A dynamic layout plugin for jQuery The flip-side of CSS floats

Here is a code [example](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html)...

```
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box'
});
```

Here is the source on [Github](https://github.com/desandro/masonry) and an interview with [David Desandro](http://shoptalkshow.com/episodes/024-with-david-desandro/) on the Shoptalk podcast.

**Tip:** Make sure the parent container has position:relative so all the content is bound to your container.